# Using a variable within a function in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use the variable "i" and the value in another function, "izq" and "der"?.
I need to use the variable within other functions.

```
    $("#gal li a").on('click', openImg);

    function openImg(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        i = $(this).parent().index();
        $("#overlay").fadeIn();
        $("#overlay #cont_img img").attr('src', href);
    }

    $(".izq").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var izq;
        i--;
        if(i < 0){
            i = total-1;
        }
        izq = $("#galeria li a").eq(i).attr('href');
        $("#overlay #cont_img img").attr('src', izq);
    });

    $(".der").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var der;
        i = (i-1) % total;
        der = $("#gal li a").eq(i).attr('href');
        $("#overlay #cont_img img").attr('src', der);
    });
```

Comment: Declare those variables within scope of all the functions you need to use them in

Comment: But then if i is modified by a function the new functions will not have the new value of i

Comment: It will have updated value... Do share an example where you face such issue...

Comment: I need to update the value and share in the other functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best if you can declare your variable outside the function as globally.

```
$("#gal li a").on('click', openImg);

var i=0;

    function openImg(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        i = $(this).parent().index();
        $("#overlay").fadeIn();
        $("#overlay #cont_img img").attr('src', href);
    }

    $(".izq").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var izq;
        i--;
        if(i < 0){
            i = total-1;
        }
        izq = $("#galeria li a").eq(i).attr('href');
        $("#overlay #cont_img img").attr('src', izq);
    });

    $(".der").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var der;
        i = (i-1) % total;
        der = $("#gal li a").eq(i).attr('href');
        $("#overlay #cont_img img").attr('src', der);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the variable global - put it in the global scope - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you put `var i` outside those functions you should be able to use it in all functions

Answer (score 0):

Though you can make `i` a variable which is in global scope. But this may result in conflict. 
An better way is to use the `namespace` pattern .
For Example

Create an object

```
var myGlobalVariables ={};
```

Now you can add a key to this object.

```
function openImg(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        myGlobalVariables.i = $(this).parent().index();
        $("#overlay").fadeIn();
        $("#overlay #cont_img img").attr('src', href);
    }
```

And in all other functions you can use the same `object & key`. In other functions you can access it using `var m = myGlobalVariables.i;`

Answer (score 0):

You can make variables global, use them a part of an object in higher scope etc. or you can use a *closure*

```
// prints 0..9
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { console.log(i); };

// any amount of other operations

// prints 10 three times
for(var z = 0; z < 10; z++) { console.log(z); };
```

you can read more about these things [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp)